# collapsing a list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list I am trying to collapse and am having trouble once I get lower in the hierarchy. Here is my html:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>
        <a>Categories</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>Parent</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>Child</a></li>
                    <li><a>Child</a></li>
                    <li><a>Child</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>  
            <li>
                <a>Parent</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>Child</a></li>
                    <li><a>Child</a></li>
                    <li><a>Child</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>  
            <li>
                <a>Parent</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>Child</a></li>
                    <li><a>Child</a></li>
                    <li><a>Child</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>  
            <li>
                <a>Parent</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>Child</a></li>
                    <li><a>Child</a></li>
                    <li><a>Child</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>            
        </ul>                
    </li>
</ul>
```

Heres my jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.list > li a').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
    });
});
```

And here is a jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u7bczqup/

Once you click on Categories the Parents come down. When this happens, all the children of the parents are shown and not hidden. Why are these ones not hidden? Ive tried adjusting my jquery but that causes it to not work at all.

Comment: `<li>` are not hidden by default, but their parent elements are.

It might be prudent to initially hide those.

Comment: They are not hidden because jquery find searches any descendants  below it and then you are toggling them, you should use children().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not hidden because jquery find searches any descendants below it and then you are toggling them, you should use children().

Try this:

```
$(this).parent().children('ul').toggle();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u7bczqup/1/

https://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot.

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.list > li a').click(function(){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    });
});
```

The issue with using `.find()` is that it is finding all the `ul` element. You can check this by adding this line: `console.log($(this).parent().find('ul'));` This will print all the `ul` tags it is "finding" to the console. Because it is finding all of them, it is toggling all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for all unordered list elements in the method .find('ul') that are direct descendants.
It should be .find('ul:first-child') ore more precisely .children(ul:first) so it would be

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.list > li a').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().children('ul').toggle();
    });
});
```

for more refer to [jquery find method](https://api.jquery.com/find/)